# Group data by consecutive points in Influxdb

Tags: influxdb

Suppose I have this data:

```
time    value
----    ----
0       28
1       27
2       26
3       25
4       26
5       27
```

I want to get values greater than 25 separated by consecutive points, as follow:

```
Group1
time    value
----    ----
0       28
1       27
2       26

Group2
time    value
----    ----
4       26
5       27
```

Is there anyway to do that with one query or should I post-process the data?